# Как выполнить SQL- запрос для импортирования данных в MySQL в Docker контейнере?

Tags: mysql, sql, docker

Помогите разобраться, мне необходимо импортировать данные из файла csv в локальную базу MySQL, которая является образом Docker.
я могу импортировать данные в MySQL когда она установлена локально, но вот с Docker(ом) встречался очень редко, поэтому не в курсе как это можно реализовать, может быть у кого-то была такая практика? Как можно это выполнить?

Comment: Нужно загрузить этот CSV в любое место, которое доступно MySQL-серверу (лучше всего, конечно, на локальный том). А потом LOAD DATA. Плюс нужны соотв. права (FILE privilege) и настройки сервера (@@secure_file_priv, @@local_infile).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если на локальном компьютере есть mysql клиент, то подключитесь при помощи него к вашему серверу базы данных и выполниете загрузку:

```
mysql -u[USER_NAME] -p -e 'LOAD DATA ...'
```

Синтаксис запроса [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).

При этом у контейнера mysql должен быть открыт порт во вне. Проверить это можно командой `docker-compose port [MYSQL_SERVICE_NAME] 3306`.  Если порт не открыт во вне, то открыть его можно прописав в файле docker-compose.override.yml опцию:

```
ports:
   - "3306:3306"
```

Comment: А могли бы Вы подробнее описать ответ?
я не понимаю, что значит "Если на локальном компьютере есть mysql клиент, то подключитесь при помощи него к вашему серверу базы данных и выполниете загрузку"
Тут вы имеете ввиду, что он должен быть установлен на ПК как контенер Docker или как самостоятельная программа или что-то другое?

Comment: mysql клиентом может быть консольная утилита mysql или тот же phpstorm или mysql workbench или какая-нибудь другая IDE. Я имел ввиду, что одна из указанных программ может быть установлена у вас на компьютере